# Is calling is_valid() on a form that has hidden values required?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-1.7

I have a form with a bunch of fields but I also pass in values like the current page they submitted the form from and the user, which are hidden fields.

So from what I understand is_valid() will fail because of that. So do I need to run is_valid()?

For example, one of my forms has the line:

```
self.fields['user'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the form will be validated for all fields - depending upon required/non-required or default etc - for hidden fields as well with respect to provided data.

If you want to save or use the submitted data, you should validate the form using `is_valid()`.

Comment: It won't ever be valid if I have this line `self.fields['user'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()`, right?

Comment: It will be valid if you populate the hidden input with an user id.

Comment: Also, the OP should consider that just because the field is hidden when the page is rendered doesn't mean it will be when a user submits the form, or that the input will contain the type of data the OP intends. In other words, always validate your data.